# How to find a symmetric predecessor / successor

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

Lets say we have a binary tree $T$ and we want to insert key $k$. Now, assuming $k\not\in T$, how do we find the symmetric predecessor/successor of $k$?

Does this relate to (pre/in/post)-order traversals in some way?

Comment: 1. What kind of binary tree?  The answer will depend a lot.  Is it a binary search tree?  What invariants are guaranteed on the placement of the keys in $T$?  2. Can you define "symmetric predecessor/successor"?  3. What research have you done?  This kind of thing is covered in standard textbooks.

Comment: 1.) This concept should apply to any binary tree organised through a total order $\sqsubseteq$ on the set of keys. 2) So far I've seen that the symmetric predecessor corresponds to the predecessor in an in-order traversal. 3) Yes, it seems to be something trivial since it's directly related to the in-order traversal. However, most textbooks just use the term symmetric predecessor without showing a precise way how to find it given a node to start searching from. In this case, let's just assume that we inserted $k$ in the binary tree and now are searching for it's symmetric predecessor.

Comment: a. Please edit the question to include these clarifications.  Comments exist only to help you improve your question, and can disappear at any time.  b. I don't know what you mean by "organized through a total order".  I know what a total order is, but I think you need to define exactly how you have in mind that the tree is organized.  A binary tree is a very broad concept that leaves many possible ways that the keys could be ordered. c. Again, please define what you mean by symmetric predecessor/successor (in the question).

Comment: Are there any time constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric predecessor corresponds to the predecessor in an in-order traversal. So for a key $k$ we may find it's predecessor in two ways:

1. Find the place where $k$ would be inserted and perform an in-order traversal backwards from there on. For the details check this algorithm here which describes the dual problem of finding a symmetric successor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cPbNCrdotA
2. Call a modified version of floor, which finds the largest value strictly smaller than $k$ in the tree.

Here's how floor and ceil can be implemented:
"Floor and ceiling. If a given key key is less than the key at the root of a BST, then the floor of key (the largest key in the BST less than or equal to key) must be in the left subtree. If key is greater than the key at the root, then the floor of key could be in the right subtree, but only if there is a key smaller than or equal to key in the right subtree; if not (or if key is equal to the key at the root) then the key at the root is the floor of key. Finding the ceiling is similar, interchanging right and left."

For further details refer to:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/

Comment: Please elaborate to include the main ideas in the answer.  We discourage link-only answers: we don't want to be just a link farm; and if the link dies, link-only answers become useless.  Thank you!